# Set windows 7 to my web site server

Tags: iis

i have a windows 7 professional and i install IIS 7.0 and i write simple asp.net application,i go to whatismy ip address site and i find the my public ip ,when i request my asp.net app from local client my web page show fine,but i want access my web page from my friend computer,but when i write public ip address and my iis app ,my web page not show the my web page!,how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Most likely, your ISP doesn't expose port 80 to the outside world, because of the serious security implications. If they do, though, then you'll want to check your router configuration to ensure you are opening up the port.

Comment: Have you set your router/firewall to forward port 80 to your Windows 7 PC?

Comment: thanks my friend,my modem tp link ,how can i check port is open on my modem,and how can i inbound port 80 in firewall or how can i set iis to other port?

Comment: no my public ip is 5.250.31.280

Comment: @CharlesH how can i to set firewall to port 80?

Comment: @lzam my web page on my home computer,and i want to access my web page in my office?

Comment: Do you know the tp link router model as they make quite a few different types..

Comment: @CharlesH my modem model is :TD-W8951ND

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a web browser and enter the internal IP address of your router in the address bar of your browser.

By default the IP address should be set to 192.168.1.1.

You should see a box prompting you for your username and password.
Enter your username and password now.

The Default TP-Link TD-W8951ND Router Username is: admin
The Default TP-Link TD-W8951ND Router Password is: admin

Once logged in to your TP-Link TD-W8951ND router click the Advanced Setup link near the top of the page.

You should now see a new menu. Click NAT.

Click the Virtual Server link near the center of the page.

Change the options here to

Rule 1
HTTP
Protocol ALL
Start Port 80
End Port 80
Internal IP of your Windows 7 machine

Save this and retest!

Comment: thanks,but in my modem just have a https protocol,and start port can not set 80 and modem show alarm to set 8080 port number

Comment: There will be a way you can add a 'custom' potocol so you do not need to select one from the list... however to check this works you can add any port such as 8080 and then externally you type your IP in a browser like so http://5.250.31.280:8080 that will specify the port as 8080

Comment: If you need to use https, then it's port 443 that you need to forward and to configure in IIS.